# Where to install dynamic link libraries on Windows and OSX?

Tags: windows, macos, dll, installation

I need to install a DLL on Windows and OSX, it will be used by several apps and dlls placed allover the system, but I'm 100% sure it will always be my apps and I don't need any kind of versioning, meaning that if the DLL is replaced by a newer version (or older for that matter), it will work just fine. I also need 32-bit and 64-bit versions.

It looks like these are the proper paths:

```
OSX : /usr/lib (merged binary for 32 & 64)
Windows: C:\Windows\System32 (here the sources vary)
```

On OSX it seems working fine. On Windows however it doesn't. I need to support Windows XP,7,8... And on Windows 8.1 it sometimes just didn't work - the file was clearly there, but systém said the DLL is missing. It also seems like the folder for 32-bit (SysWOW64) and 64-bit (system32) are actually pointing to the same location, so I assume Microsoft has been "fixing" the naming mess.

Anyway one location it always worked is here:

```
C:\Windows
```

but it doesn't seem to be designed for that. So how is it?

Comment: Don't install private libs in `/usr/lib`, use the `/usr/local/lib`.

Comment: Putting DLLs in the system32 directory is strongly discouraged, although it works for backwards compatibility reasons.  If you choose this option, the 32-bit DLL should go in syswow64 and the 64-bit DLL in system32 (if the installer is 32-bit, then you can use the sysnative link to access the real system32 folder).  The conventional solution, if you don't want to use versioning (the side-by-side system) is to either put a copy of the DLL next to each executable that uses it, or to give it its own folder in Program Files and load it dynamically.

Comment: Well, that's a LOT of work for such a simple thing - there will be literally hundreds of these DLLs (plugins...), all acting like a simple wrappers to a few functions in the shared DLL. Cloning the shared DLL is not an option for obvious reasons. Loading it dynamically seems like extremely ineffective approach. What is wrong about placing it in system32? And what is wrong about placing it into c:/windows. As far as I understand, all you need is a place at PATH env.